# I cannot pull data from JSON object- array after ajax post?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, express

My site pass data passes through json objects via Angular's $http post ok.

Here is my site if you want to see the console.logs and responses:

http://cpcarpet.com/#/

I decided to try it appplication /json after getting x-form-ur; encoding to work fine since I will eventually push it to MongoDB.

However while simple objects work fine via req.body.____

more complex json obejects + arrays are not working. I'm also seeing my response status is gateway time out (504) but mail is being delivered just fine via amazon SES.

Here is my html email, I've tried the following variations but all return undefined. Console.log shows my data is going through just fine.

```
replyTo: req.body.user[0].email,

subject: 'Clean Path Contact from '+ req.body.user.fname + ' '+ req.body[0].user.phone, // REQUIRED.
text: req.body.user + '\n' + '\n'  + 'Customer Name address: ' + req.body.user.fname[0] + '\n' + 'Customer email address: ' + req.body.user[0].email + '\n' +'Customer Phone Number: ' + req.body.user[0].phone,
};
```

what my objects typically look like:

```
      { user: {[
{
  "fName":"",
  "lName":"",

},
        {
            "name": "roomsclean1",
            "price": 27,
            "title": "Room(s) to clean",

          }, {
            "name": "roomsprotect1 ",
            "price": 62,
          }
    ]}
```

or I just use an array of objects [{username: jim, lname: thomas}] yet req.body[0].username returns undefined.

Contrast that with objects like this: they work fine and the email receives the data:

```
{username: jim, lastname: thomas}

    req.body.username
```

Comment: Your structure is actually wrong. `user` is also an `object`. So it shud contain a `key:value` pair, instead it contains an array.

Comment: http://cpcarpet.com/#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
"user": [
    {
        "fName": "",
        "lName": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "roomsclean1",
        "price": 27,
        "title": "Room(s) to clean"
    },
    {
        "name": "roomsprotect1 ",
        "price": 62
    }
]
```

}

This should be your example json. Now when you try to get the zeroth element of the user array, You will be able to get it.

Comment: That is same structure I'm using. Does not work. I originally just had array, but it also did not work.

Comment: Try to do console.log (req.body) and see what it prints and make sure that the user key is a string.

Comment: Well it seems that you are sending a array and not a JSON.

Comment: I recently changed it to try something different.

Comment: Well past option would be to create a json and check the request data in the network tab. Copy the form data and try to validate it with jsonlint.com .

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON structure was wrong , use this structure and try with user[0].fname = demo

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "fName": "demo",
            "lName": "dmo"
        },
        {
            "name": "roomsclean1",
            "price": 27,
            "title": "Room(s) to clean"
        },
        {
            "name": "roomsprotect1 ",
            "price": 62
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That is same structure I'm using. Does not work. I originally just had array, but it also did not work.

Comment: store this json in variable e.g var s = jsonOb ; console.log(s.user[0].fName)

Comment: I'm not able to see u response.